# jQuery timestamp format

Tags: jquery, timestamp

I was looking for a method of getting timestamp in jquery, like we do it in php by `time()` (which is seconds since Jan 1 1970).

I tried `event.timeStamp`, but it output 9 digits starting with 9, which I know is incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Math.floor(+new Date() / 1000)
```

Answer (score 8):

Use jquery.now()
http://jsbin.com/icesab/edit#javascript,html